# Execting one Matlab file using another

Tags: matlab

This might be a pretty basic question but I was not able to find an answer for this.

I am trying to run a matlab code that has two arguments passed to it : 
1. Name of an existing matlab code
2. An integer number.
This would be the command I would run in the command window in Matlab-

```
>> auto_caller mytest.m 10
```

Here *auto_caller* is the main code and it should execute the file *mytest.m* 10 times.

This is what I tried -

```
function [arguments] = auto_caller(filename, iterations)
    for i = 0 : str2num(iterations)
         filename
    end
end
```

But when I run it, the output is just -

```
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
mytest.m
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks,
Shreedhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the name of the matlab source file containing the function, pass a function handle:

```
auto_caller @mytest 10
```

This is the same way that Mathworks-provided optimization algorithms accept goal functions, GUI widgets accept event callback functions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

Use `run(scriptname_here)`

Comment: I never knew there was a run function. +1 for teaching me something new

Comment: FWIW, `run` is just a wrapper for `evalin` and cannot accept input arguments.

Comment: @excaza that is interesting as well. thanks for that info.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a file by using the `eval` function

```
function runScript(file,n)
    for i = 1:n
       eval(strrep(file,'.m','')) 
    end
end
```

Comment: 'eval' works for me!! In fact I tried all the answers and they all work.

Comment: However, in the loop, we need to convert the value of `n` into number. `str2num`. Because using `n` as it is gave me an error.

Comment: with the way you are passing values into the function, yes you would need to convert it. I was assuming you could call the function as `runScript('somefile',10)`